# Make unique key as a Foreign key?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

Hello i want to make unique key as a foreign key but i got an error  i already checked [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/119000/how-to-reference-a-unique-key-constraint-in-parent-table-as-a-foreign-key-in-chi)

**mY member Table**

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `member` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `contact` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `facebook` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `cnic` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `expertise` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `com_code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

and my profile image tabl

```
create table profileimage(
imageid int primary key not null,
username varchar(100) foreign key references member(username) 
ON DELETE CASCADE
 ON UPDATE CASCADE,
imagepath varchar(255) not null
);
```

and error i faced
*#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'foreign key references member(username) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,' at line 6*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can have a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint that references a column with a `UNIQUE` constraint.

The syntax error you get is because you didn't provide a datatype for the column. It should be the same type as the referenced column: `username varchar(50)`.

Another issue is the syntax for foreign constraints. If you put them "inline", i.e immediately after the column definition, you skip the `FOREIGN KEY` and have only `REFERENCES`:

```
-- Don't do this in MySQL !!!!
CREATE TABLE profileimage
( imageid int  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  username varchar(50)
     REFERENCES member (username) 
     ON DELETE CASCADE
     ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  imagepath varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB ;
```

or you put them separately, with the `FOREIGN KEY` keyword:

```
-- Do this in MySQL
CREATE TABLE profileimage
( imageid int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  username varchar(50),
  imagepath varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (username)
     REFERENCES member (username) 
     ON DELETE CASCADE
     ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB ;
```

**Big surprise:** Both syntaxes work in MySQL with a catch: the first is parsed for syntax validity (and it passes) but **the foreign key is not created!** (you get a warning)

The second syntax works fine.

Answer (score 2):

[MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

> Furthermore, MySQL parses but ignores “inline REFERENCES
>   specifications” (as defined in the SQL standard) where the references
>   are defined as part of the column specification. MySQL accepts
>   REFERENCES clauses only when specified as part of a separate FOREIGN
>   KEY specification. For storage engines that do not support foreign
>   keys (such as MyISAM), MySQL Server parses and ignores foreign key
>   specifications.

So it should be:

```
create table profileimage(
    imageid int primary key not null,
    username varchar(50) not null,
    imagepath varchar(255) not null,

    foreign key (username) references member(username)
    on delete cascade on update cascade
);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a pity that MySQL has not supported this for 20 years, just look at (in chronological order): [bug #4919](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=4919), [bug #17943](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=17943), [bug #102904](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=102904).

The task would be rather simple to address, with not much coding involved. Otherwise *MySQL engineers*, please give a clear warning that the functionality is still not supposed to work. Do not feed wrong expectations.

MariaDB started to support this with release [10.5](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-20729).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/188243)